# how to show data of model.ts in my code, using ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

now i trying array data modeling using ionic2.

i created 'model.ts' in 'src/app/models' and declared in 'setting.ts' with array data.

next, i called it to 'setting.html'.

By the way...There is a some problem. 
build and run were success. but any datas didn't show in screen..

not Error, i dont know where is wrong..

please find wrong point and fix that.

there is my code..

> workoutlist-model.ts

```
export class WorkoutlistModel {
constructor(public Workoutlist: any[]) {
    this.Workoutlist = [];
}

addItem(nm, gl) {
    this.Workoutlist.push({
        name: nm,
        goal: gl
    });
}
removeItem(nm, gl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Workoutlist.length; i++) {
        if (this.Workoutlist[i].name == nm) {
            if (this.Workoutlist[i].goal == gl) {
                this.Workoutlist.splice(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

> setting.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WorkoutlistModel } from '../../app/models/workoutlist-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-setting',
  templateUrl: 'setting.html'
})
export class Setting {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    new WorkoutlistModel([{ name: 'Push-Up', goal: 100 },
      { name: 'Squat', goal: 150 },
      { name: 'Sit-Up', goal: 45 }]);
  }
}
```

> setting.html - the part using this.

```
<ion-content style="height: 200px; outline: green">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let WO of WorkoutlistModel;">
    <button ion-item>
      <div style="float: left;padding: 0px;">name : {{WO.name}}</div>
      <div style="float: right;padding: 0px;">goal : {{WO.goal}}</div>
    </button>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: the html is of setting component?

Comment: @suraj no, just home.html & ts. i changed the name according to the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent declared or assigned `WorkoutlistModel`

Also WorklistModel is  class and not an array to traverse with `*ngFor`

```
export class Setting {
  workListModel:any;//declare
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.workListModel = new WorkoutlistModel([{ name: 'Push-Up', goal: 100 },
      { name: 'Squat', goal: 150 },
      { name: 'Sit-Up', goal: 45 }]);//assign
  }
}
```

In Html

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let WO of workListModel.getList();"><!-- get the list of items from class to traverse. may have to create this function -->
    <button ion-item>
      <div style="float: left;padding: 0px;">name : {{WO.name}}</div>
      <div style="float: right;padding: 0px;">goal : {{WO.goal}}</div>
    </button>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. i created getList in 'workoutlist-model.ts'  like this [getList(){
        return this.Workoutlist;
    }] but runtime Error happened 'Cannot read property 'getList' of undefined''

Comment: sorry.. had an error in html of my code. you should use the variable not the class name

Comment: than.. are you saying change function to the variable in html? or change return type in ts?

Comment: no.. my html didnt have the variable I am setting in the component.. click on `edited min ago` to see the revision.

Comment: oh~! i Resolved.^^ i forgot change code asking @raj... thank you every one

Answer (score 0):

You are not injecting the model. So change it to this.

```
constructor( Workoutlist: any[]) {
    this.Workoutlist = Workoutlist;
}
```

Comment: oh~! i Resolved!.. I saw your code and fixed the last error.really thank you~

Comment: @Elessar happy to help. accept it as answer if it solved the issue.